# Snappy source packages?

Tags: ubuntu-core

In a Debian system, any package can be built from source by issuing the  `dpkg-buildpackage` command.

In snappy Ubuntu, there does not seem to be anything comparable to either `dpkg-buildpackage` or `apt-get source`. Why is this so?

Answer (score 4):

You can build a snappy package like this, in the folder of the app to build, run

```
snappy build .
```

With a .

You may need this too

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snappy-dev/tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install snappy-tools bzr
```

To learn the basics how to build a simple snappy app on your Ubuntu desktop, get the snappy‐examples code repository.

```
 bzr branch lp:~snappy-dev/snappy-hub/snappy-examples
```

They have provided a few example apps to try out. All of them are published for Ubuntu Core in the cloud repository. If you want to try them on Ubuntu Core without building them yourself, you can use snappy search and install them directly.

Let's walk through a build from source of "hello-world":

```
 cd snappy-examples/hello-world
```

Take a moment to inspect the contents of this directory. The key is the snappy packaging meta information that you will find in the meta/ directory and the package.yaml file. This information is all it takes to package your snappy application and share it with snappy users. The contents of meta/package.yaml are documented in the [packaging guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/packaging-format-apps/).

Now that you are familiar with the internals of how a snappy package source tree looks like, let's create the hello-world .snap package. For that simply run:

```
 snappy build .
```

This will produce a snappy package in your current working directory, which you can install on your snappy system using the snappy-remote command:

```
 snappy-remote --url=ssh://localhost:8022 install ./hello-world_1.0.5_all.snap
```

Of course, you need to provide the address of the running snappy virtual machine, the example above is correct if you are using KVM locally, if you are on the cloud then it will be a different hostname and is unlikely to require a custom port. Log in to your snappy and run the hello-world.hello command to see it yourself:

```
hello-world.echo
Hello World
```

[All this is from the official documentation.](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/tutorials/build-snaps/)

Comment: From what I understand, snappy build does not turn source code into binaries. Rather, it turns a directory into a tarball. I think you must precompile the code manually.

Comment: This will produce a snappy package in your current working directory, which you can install on your snappy system using the snappy-remote command ,. should make a .snap not a tar ball, would you like me to add a example for you to test ?

Comment: `snappy build .` makes a .snap file (essentially a tarball, yes) that can be installed on the system, this is a snappy binary package. I will add more info to the answer

Comment: Thanks everyone. Apparently 'snapcraft' is the answer I was looking for (developed after I posed the question, apparently).